# Tableview reloadData is not being executed -- sometimes

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, xcode4, reloaddata

I have a view controller that is called from 2 different places.

1) I call it from a root controller.  It is shown and populated.  The add button works perfectly.  I open a modal form, get the information and return it to the view controller via it's delegate.

```
- (void)itemsAddViewController:(AddItemView *)itemsAddViewController didAddItem
  (OrdersDetails *)orderDetail;
{
    if (orderDetail) {
        [orderDetailItems addObject:orderDetail];
}   
[self fetchOrderDetails];
[lineItemsTableView reloadData];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

However, when I call it from another view (on the right side of the split view), this same code does NOT reload the table.  It adds the data -- if I leave the form and come back, the data is there, but the tableview is not being refreshed.  When I step through the code, it gets the the line, but then goes over it like it doesn't see it.

Comment: Sounds like `lineItemsTableView ` is `nil` in one case but you haven't show enough code to say for sure. What is different about the two cases where you present this controller?

Comment: I don't think lineItemsTableView is nil -- it shows existing lines, just not the new one.  Now that you mention it though, the second time it is being popped into a modal form.  Would that make a difference?  I can do it without that, but I'll have to rethink some program flow.

Comment: Presenting the view controller as a modal should make no difference but if how you create it differs then that might be important.
I don't doubt that your table exists (eventually) but suspect that the `lineItemsTableView` property may not point to it when you call `itemsAddViewCOntroller:didAddItem:`. Is the view loaded at that point? Do you know that `lineItemsTableView` has been set correctly?
Again, without seeing a more complete example it is impossible to know where your problem arises.

Comment: What code do you need to see?  I can post some more, I just don't really know what's relevant. . .

Comment: I think where you construct your view controller(s) and table view would be relevant. Also debug `itemsAddViewController:didAddItem:` and confirm if `lineItemsTableView` is nil or not so that I don't waste your time guessing what the problem might be. I'm betting that when you call `itemsAddViewController:didAddItem:` your table view is not visible and sometimes has been unloaded (depending on if your app received a memory warning).

Comment: lineItemsTableView was indeed nil.  I'm still not sure why (I suspect that somehow it was being "hidden"), but I've changed over and I'm using a navigation controller and it's working fine, so I'm not going to waste any more of your time on it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a modal view controller is presented over the view controller containing `-itemsAddViewController:didAddItem:` the underlying controller's view is not visible and will therefore be unloaded if the controller receives a memory warning.

As a result your view may not be loaded and your `lineItemsTableView` outlet may be `nil` when you call `-itemsAddViewController:didAddItem:`. Your call to `reloadData` would need to move to `-viewWillAppear:` to avoid assuming that your controller's view can have a persistent state when it is not visible.